# Dynamic view layout in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement the layout below in **SwiftUI** - a cell that can be used in `VStack` or `List` but I'm stuck. Is it possible to achieve this layout without `Grid` (I have to support iOS 15+)?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (all styling for demonstration - didn't try to recreate the original post):

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline, spacing: 20) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Title can have only one line, Title can have only one line")
            .font(.callout)
            .lineLimit(1)
        Text("This text can have 2 lines and can be shrinked")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .lineLimit(2)
    }
    
    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
        Toggle("", isOn: .constant(true))
            .labelsHidden()
        Spacer()
        Text("Longer Status text")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: 100, alignment: .trailing)
            .fixedSize()
    }
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
.padding()
.border(Color.secondary)
```

The key point here is the `fixedSize` modifier which essentially "hugs" the view vertically. Without that, the `Spacer` would expand the view vertically and claim all available space.

Seems to cover all the cases you have mentioned above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Alladinian. In your solution the status text on the right side has always maximum width - 100. So when the status text is shorter, both texts on the left side do not expand their width as needed.

Comment: @Deny See my latest edits.

Comment: Great! I ended with the very same solution but the fixed size for the HStack was the missing part. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, but the main issue is the alignment of both rows: to keep the top row (title and toggle) at the very top and the second row (text and status) at the very bottom, and keep it simple, its is necessary to *fix the height* of the view to a certain value.

If that can work for you, you can use 2 `VStack`s separated by a 20 pt spacer and embedded in  an `HStack`. The example below fixes the height of the view to 70 pt.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("Title")
//                Text("Title can be very, very big and not have enough space be be shown entirely")
                .font(.footnote)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            
            Spacer()
            
//                Text("Short text")
            Text("This text can have two lines and can also be shrinkable to make enough space for the toggle on the right")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .layoutPriority(2)

        }
        .layoutPriority(1)
        
        Spacer(minLength: 20)
        
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {}
                .frame(alignment: .top)
            
            Spacer()
            
//                Text("On")
            Text("Status row can be a lot longer than you think")
                .font(.footnote)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: 100, alignment: .trailing)

        }
        
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: 70)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not able to have a fixed height for the cell. It has to be dynamic. I ended with something similar but some of the elements always lay out differently than I need.

Comment: And the proposed solution has another issue - the text on the right side should affect the width of texts on the left side.